# Android check if app is selected for mocking location

Tags: android, mocking, location

my app uses mocking location, so I want to check, if my app is selected in the dev settings. Since ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION is deprecated, I can not find how to do it. There must be a similar setting, that saves the app that can uses mocking location, but I can not find it anywhere. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use location.isFromMockProvider():

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read this, but I want to check if my app is enabled for mocking location before i enable the mocking location service. If I want to use .isFromMockProvider(), I would first have to enable my mocking location service, no matter if it will work or not, and then check the current location. I hope there is another way, because that is not what i want to do.